In R convert dataframe to value?
New to R. I wanted to create an object/value called "x" that is the count of all observations in a dataframe df.
Here's my code:
x <- df %>% count()

However, this causes 'x' to be a dataframe of 1 observation and 1 column.
How do I make it so that it's a object/value (not sure where the actual name is). In other words, if I do:
x <- 58

That creates an object called x with just 58 as the value. It's not a dataframe and that's what I'm looking to create.

Do you just want x <- nrow(df)? Usually we use count to count the number of occurrences of a certain category.

Yes! I didn't realize nrow was a thing...I think in this case, count() and nrow() probably yield the same number. nrow works, thank you!

Axeman's comment was correct. Doing x <- nrow(df) worked perfectly.
